# Chunks of texts being repeated multiple times

Tags: python, text-files

I have a text file with content similar to below:

```
----------------------------------------
Title: Textbook
Client: ABC
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Title: Comic book
Client: DEF
----------------------------------------
```

My script seems to be outputting duplicate dictionaries and I don't want that, but I'm not sure what is wrong.

```
data = {}
with open("sample.log", "r") as f_input:

    for line in f_input:
        if not line.startswith('----------------------------------------'):

            key, value = line.strip().split(':',1)
            data[key] = value.strip()
            print(data)
```

Current output:

```
{'Title': 'Textbook', 'Client': 'ABC'}
{'Title': 'Textbook', 'Client': 'ABC'}
{'Title': 'Textbook', 'Client': 'ABC'}
{'Title': 'Comic book', 'Client': 'DEF'}
{'Title': 'Comic book', 'Client': 'DEF'}
{'Title': 'Comic book', 'Client': 'DEF'}
```

Expected output:

```
{'Title': 'Textbook', 'Client': 'ABC'}
{'Title': 'Comic book', 'Client': 'DEF'}
```

Comment: You're printing the entire `data` dictionary every time a non-divider line is encountered, plus you never clear it to capture the next pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You print the entire contents of the dictionary `data` on each change in *any* of its elements.

The first change is adding the key `Title:Textbook`. The next change is adding `Client:ABC` – but because you print the entire dictionary, you get to see *both* the original key `Title` as the *new* key `Client`. This gets worse with the next entry for `Comic book`. Now that line contains a new client name but the key `Title` still holds the wrong data.

At the start of each new entry (indicated, apparently, by those `-----` lines) you should clear your `data`. Also, you cannot store more than a single key with the same name in the same dictionary; you can only have *one* `Title` and *one* `Client`. After you read and store the next line for `Client`, you've totally overwritten the first data item with new information.

To avoid all of this, build a new dictionary and add it to a *list* instead:

```
data = []
temp_dict = {}
with open("sample.log", "r") as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        if not line.startswith('----------------------------------------'):
            key, value = line.strip().split(':',1)
            temp_dict[key] = value.strip()
        else:
            if temp_dict:
                data.append(temp_dict)
            temp_dict = {}
print(data)
```

with the result, now a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'Title': 'Textbook', 'Client': 'ABC'},
 {'Title': 'Comic book', 'Client': 'DEF'}]
```

Comment: thank you so much. It worked. I guess I learned something more. Appreciate it.